# Incorrect wxMaxima sha256sum() output

Tags: sha256, maxima

I'm trying to calculate a hash using **sha256sum** function from **stringproc** package.

The output is obviously wrong for me (Windows 7, maxima-5.38.1).

E.g. hash from the [docs example](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_84.html#sha1sum):

```
(%i1) string: sha256sum("foo bar baz");
(%o1) dbd318c1c462aee872f41109a4dfd3048871a03dedd0fe0e757ced57dad6f2d7
```

For me it outputs **562fae81675643664087303002ecc95c547cf8a6c8173f3bc046da4244bcaef4**

Other hash functions from the same package (SHA1, MD5) seem to work fine.
I've also tried running from xMaxima as well as the *sha1.lisp* file from version 5.37.2 with the very same result.

Somehow I suspect this to be related with maxima to run under Windows.

Did anybody see such issues?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see the same result as you, I'm running Maxima 5.39.0 on Linux. If this web site http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html is correct, the documented output is correct. I don't know why it seems to have become incorrect.

Comment: @RobertDodier, thanks for confirming. I've double-checked the output from the example with a couple of online hash calculators. They prove the hash from above. I think I'll file a bug and will look for devs to respond.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Maxima. [As described by one of developers](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/3300/#8bb9):

> The correct result was only computed when Maxima was compiled with gcl

Since then it was fixed. I've tested and can confirm that **sha256sum()** now gives correct hashes.

One can download the fixed **sha1.lisp** file [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/stringproc/sha1.lisp).